# Eigenvalue of f and df

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

Given 1 is not an eigenvalue of $df$ at $x_0$, take a chart $(U,\phi)$ around $x_0.$ Then in this coordinate neighborhood, think of $f$ as a map from open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say $B$), to itself with $f(0)=0.$ Now consider we have a function $f:B\rightarrow B$  such that $f(0)=0.$ Then $det(f - id)(0)\neq 0$.

But I thought it should be det$(df-id)(0) \neq 0$? Did we assume f is linear map so f = df here?

Comment: No, $f$ is not linear, so you're talking about the eigenvalues of $df_0$. So, yes, if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $df_0$, then $df_0-I$ is a nonsingular matrix.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin. This is GP 1.6.10 which follows 1.6.9 where assumes $f$ is linear. So I'll assume $f = df$ so that I can proceed with my proof...

Comment: No, you can't do that. Apply the preceding problem to $df_0$.

Comment: Oh what I am thinking about. All I need for inverse function theorem is det$(df-id) \neq 0$. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered by Ted Shifrin.

Yes this should be det$(df - id)_0 \neq 0$. I can't assume that $f$ is linear.